# socialauth-android - Only Facebook sharing working other networks are not working?

Tags: android

I am using [socialauth-android](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/) in my application. I have done everything mentioned in tutorial and there example code. but after that in testing only facebook share button is working. when click on other buttons in dialog nothing happens.

Comment: Hi , It seems you have add only facebook keys in oauth_consumer.properties. Please check your oauth_consumer.properties contains keys and secrets of other providers too.

In case issue still not resolves, please post your stack trace.

Comment: 5 out 1 time open the facebook dialog,otherwise it show the error There was a network error.